# How to make this if statement shorter?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Can I make this statement shorter?

```
if(abc=='value1' || abc=='value2' || abc=='value3') {//do something}
```

to make it look similar to this:

```
if(abc=='value1' || 'value2' || 'value3'){//do something}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Shortening your statements down too far can easily cause your code to become unreadable if you (or anyone else) has to go back and read it, say a year from now.  I'd leave it as is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Leave it as it is;
2. Use an associative array/object;
3. Use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/switch) statement.

The second form is not valid Javascript syntax.

(2) is something like:

```
var abcOptions = {
  "value1" : true,
  "value2" : true,
  "value3" : true
};
if (abcOptions[abc]) {
  ...
}
```

(3) is:

```
switch (abc) {
  case "value1":
    ...
    break;
  case "value2":
    ...
    break;
  case "value3":
    ...
    break;
}
```

Personally I'm not a huge fan of this from a readability point of view but it's a reasonable approach with a large number of values.

I don't necessarily recommend this but it might be an option in certain circumstances. If you're only dealing with three values stick with:

```
if (abc == "value1" || abc == "value2" || abc == "value3") {
  ...
}
```

as it's much more readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].indexOf(abc) != -1)
```

This one manages to remain somewhat readable, but you should leave your original code as-is unless you have way more conditions.

Comment: Or potentially:
if ("value1 value2 value3".split(" ").indexOf(abc) != -1)
or make it a reusable function:
function hasToken(text, token) { 
 return text.split(" ").indexOf(token) != -1; 
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use a switch:

```
switch (abc) { case 'value1': case 'value2': case 'value3': {
  // do something
}}
```

Or written in a more traditional form:

```
switch (abc) {
  case 'value1':
  case 'value2':
  case 'value3': {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Upvote for using the fall-through case syntax.  It isn't any shorter than the OP's code, though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(abc.match(/^value[1-3]$/)) {
    //doSomething....
}
```

Comment: My comment on the OP's question still stands.  Readability has to count for something.  This is not nearly as readable.  Getting all "fancy" is not necessary if you're sacrificing readability.

Comment: I am all for code readability, just that this specific regex aren't that fancy (and imho, rather readable). But considering the values are arbiturary, I suppose you are right. :)

Comment: Seems the best solution to making the statement shorter. Or similarly:
/^(value1|value2|value3)$/.test(abc)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( abc.search(/value[123]/) != -1 ) ...do your stuff ...
```

Comment: `xxxvalue1xxx` will return 0 as well

Comment: So would myvalue2blahblah. What's the point? I think he could figure out to do /^value[123]$/ if that were a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `switch` statement. Like this:

```
switch(abc) {
    'value1':
    'value2':
    'value3':
         // do something
         break;
    default:
         // noop
}
```

But your original `if` with `||` is probably still preferable.